# Google Sheets XPath Scraping

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have exhausted my google-fu and my brain just cannot connect the pieces, I need this explained to me.

I'm trying to scrape data off Oanda regarding its rates, spreads, historical data, etc, and import it into google spreadsheets.

I want data from this page: 
https://www.oanda.com/forex-trading/markets/live

I'd like to be able to pull the ask, bid, and spread into a google sheet so I can do calculations using live updated information.

How can I get specific values out of the tables? For instance, I want the first value out of the line that's labelled "Spread". The value should be about 4.1 (at the time of writing this)

So I got the xpath by using google chrome developer tools, right-click on the element and select "copy xpath". Since I'm not a programmer I dont know any other way for arriving at a specific element from the tables.

I tried the following function in google spreadsheets:

=IMPORTXML("https://www.oanda.com/forex-trading/markets/live","//*[@id='pair_AUD_CAD']/td[4]")

but it returns

"#N/A - Error, imported content is empty"

What can I do to get the value?

Some of the potential problems that I've variously come across in searching are pulling data from JavaScript because the data I want is imported from another page? if that's the case how do I source the data?

I've also noticed people discussing the version of sheets being used.

The closest query to this I found had a solution that involved formatting but I was unable to replicate the result.

I've also had a strange thing happen where the importxml seemed to calculate and then returned a blank/empty cell. No error, or parse error nothing like that.

It seems I simply cannot import data from Oanda?

Answer (score 0):

Some sites protects themselfes and IMPORTXML() function not work. Try any simple selector to test, for example: `//h1`

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTXML only can read the source file located at the URL, not the resource files. Checking the source file at https://www.oanda.com/forex-trading/markets/live there is no tag with id equal to pair_AUD_CAD, so IMPORTXML could not found it.

Resources

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)